# How to display dialogbox function from another dialogbox function in Win32?

Tags: c++, c, windows

I have created a dialogbox in win32. That dialog have some text and a button.

If I press the button, I want to show another dialogbox, that have 2 textboxes. I already use Dialogboxparam function. But i have problem to get "Control_id not found" error, when i try to get 2nd dialogbox text values.

So I will use DialogboxindirectParam function, but it cant invoke the dialogbox.
Here is my code:

this is my dialog function:

```
int CALLBACK SecurityOptionsDialog::PasswordDlg(HWND hDlg,UINT msg,WPARAM  wp, LPARAM lParam)   
{  


}
```

calling dialog function:

```
case c:

DialogBoxIndirectParamA(hInst,(LPDLGTEMPLATE)(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_PWD)),_hwnd,PasswordDlg,lparam);

break;
```

Comment: In your question, your dialg function contains no code.  Also, how does "case c:" not produce a compiler error?

Comment: Hai blank...i do some work like... GuiHelper::ExtractControlText(_hwnd,IDC_NAME,&cpUserName);now IDC_NAME values cant getvalues."Control_id not found" error will occured...case c is not right,that's case IDC_PWD...

Comment: So correct your post :-)

Comment: its a logic...do u want to view my full source...